# Starting App on paired Android device from an android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing

I would like to start an Application on an android device from another android device. I'm already able to share data via sockets between devices, but I'm not sure how to go on with starting an app. Do I need some kind of service or is it  even simpler than I thought? Don't really know how to go on with this.. some kind of help is really appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Try using NFC, the devices need to touch, and that's it